# Windows 10 ToastNotification from WinForms app

Tags: c#, winforms, uwp, windows-10

I'm trying to show a Windows 10 (UWP) `ToastNotification` with adaptive content from a WinForms project. I have already:

- Set `TargetPlatformVersion` in my .csproj file to 10.0.18362.0
- Added references to `Windows.winmd` and `System.Runtime.dll`
- Set an explicit System.AppUserModel.ID (`"Demo.ToastApp"`) using the Win32 `SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID` function (at the very start of my `Main` method)

The following code runs when a button on the form is clicked:

```
XElement element = new XElement("toast",
    new XElement("visual",
        new XElement("binding",
            new XAttribute("template", "ToastGeneric"),
            new XElement("text", "Line1"),
            new XElement("text", "Line2"),
            new XElement("text", "Line3")
        )
    ),
    new XElement("actions",
        new XElement("action",
            new XAttribute("content", "Button1"),
            new XAttribute("arguments", "action=Button1")
        ),
        new XElement("action",
            new XAttribute("content", "Button2"),
            new XAttribute("arguments", "action=Button2")
        )
    )
);

var xml = new Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(element.ToString());

var toast = new ToastNotification(xml);

ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier("Demo.ToastApp").Show(toast);
```

No notification appears. No exceptions are thrown and the `Failed` event does not fire.

However, if I change the XML to the following (i.e. use a legacy toast template), the notification works:

```
XElement element = new XElement("toast",
    new XElement("visual",
        new XElement("binding",
            new XAttribute("template", "ToastText04"),
            new XElement("text", new XAttribute("id", 1), "Line1"),
            new XElement("text", new XAttribute("id", 2), "Line2"),
            new XElement("text", new XAttribute("id", 3), "Line3")
        )
    )
);
```

This is contrary to what i've read regarding toasts (see [Toast notifications from desktop apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/toast-desktop-apps)) which says that **only** `ToastGeneric` should be used and that legacy templates (such as `ToastText04`) can't be used from desktop apps.

I want adaptive content (specifically actions, so my app can respond differently depending on which one is clicked) and I cannot see what i'm doing wrong. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

(Note: I want to avoid setting my System.AppUserModel.ID in a shortcut because this functionality will ultimately reside in a class library, and I want it to work regardless of how the calling application is installed)

Comment: Hmm, those directives are based on the assumption that you want the user feedback from the toast.  You're not there yet when you can't get it to show up.  ToastText04 dates from simpler times, no feedback so no AUMID hanky-panky to get the OS to find your app back.  Too many things that can go wrong, do note the extra pain of having to configure the desktop shortcut.

Comment: refer this[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57784146/11362349)

Comment: @ketan That answer relates to legacy templates, which are already working for me. My question is about adaptive content.

Comment: @HansPassant I note that clicking the notification **does** raise the `Activated` event on the `ToastNotification`, so in that sense I am getting user feedback - but it's not much use to me without the ability to add buttons and respond differently depending on which one was clicked.

Comment: have you follow this all steps ? [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b876a/toast-notification-in-windows-10-uwp/)